Is it required to run database upgrade scripts if we are updating Sitecore 10.3 XM to 10.4 XM
We are planning to upgrade Sitecore 10.3 to 10.4.Is it required to run database scripts.

Yes, when updating Sitecore 10.3 XM to Sitecore 10.4 XM, running database upgrade scripts is typically required. Sitecore releases often include database schema changes, new features, and other updates that need to be applied to the Sitecore databases. These updates are handled through database upgrade scripts.
Sitecore provides specific upgrade documentation with each new version, which includes detailed steps for upgrading the databases. Make sure to follow the version-specific guidelines for upgrading from Sitecore 10.3 to 10.4 XM.

Yes, Sitecore recommends database upgrade in 10.4 upgrade and you should go by the recommendation.
Sitecore may change database schema under the hood for betterment. And it shares few related details in Upgrade document.
Since you are upgrading to 10.4 XM, I see below change relevant to you. This is just one example to confirm necessity of database upgrade.
Starting from Sitecore 10.4.0, the length of UserName, Email, ArchivedBy and similar fields has been
increased to 320.  

Hope this helps !
